# MFC GetClientRect/GetWindowRect after a MoveWindow

Tags: mfc, getclientrect

m_PICTURE_OD is an IDC_STATIC,

```
m_PICTURE_OD.MoveWindow(640 /*x*/,96/*y*/,480/*w*/,288/*h*/);
RECT myrect;
m_PICTURE_OD.GetClientRect(&myrect);
```

myrect.bottom = 288;
myrect.top = 0;
myrect.left = 0;
myrect.right = 480;

```
RECT myrect;
m_PICTURE_OD.GetWindowRect(&myrect);
```

myrect.bottom = 508;
myrect.top = 220;
myrect.left = 802;
myrect.right = 1282;

I'd like to reobtain myrect.left = 640, myrect.top = 96 ...

What can I do ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing screen coordinates and client coordinates. To translate between them, use `CWnd::ScreenToClient` and `CWnd::ClientToScreen`.